# Showing $6x^3 - 3x - 18 $ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The techniques I know right now to show a polynomial f(x) in Q[x] is irreducible are to show it is irreducible in some $F_p$ with p a prime f(x) has the same degree in $F_p$ as in Q[x], and the Eisenstein criteria.

I know that $6x^3-3x-18$ is irreducible in Q[x], but I don't see how to show it. The prime divisors of 18 are 2 and 3, both of which divide 6 so a simple Eisenstein doesn't work. And I've tried roots of the polynomial in $F_p$ for many p's, but it always seems to have roots. I'm guessing there is a simple way to solve this problem, does anyone know?

Comment: Try the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) or $\mathbb F_{11}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cubic polynomial is reducible, it has a linear factor, which corresponds to a  root, which your polynomial does not have in $\mathbb Q$ by the [rational root theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Alternatively, you could show that your polynomial has no root in $\Bbb F_{11}$.

Comment: Ahh thank you I don't know how I missed that somehow!